# How to turn off Centos auto generating tmp file in backup folder

Tags: centos7

My server runs on CentOS 7 and it does not set up by me. For some reasons the server automatically generates a lot of tmp files in the /backups folder and each file is over 28GB in size and my server would run out of space in a day or two.

What causes this? and how can I turn it off?